# How to make a dynamic call to and from html? So that it is sent to formData

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

I am a newbie in frontend issues.

I want to achieve that I have fully dynamic solution in the html and javascript. Which is already difficult enough, maybe via some [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call or I don't know.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('<%- fieldName%>').value = "<%- value %>";
  }
  //    document.getElementById("<%- fieldName%>").addEventListener("change", myFunction());
</script>
<div class="AknFieldContainer">
  <div class="AknFieldContainer-header">
    <label class="AknFieldContainer-label control-label" for="<%- fieldName%>">
      <%- label %>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="AknFieldContainer-inputContainer">
    <input id="<%- fieldName%>" class="AknTextField <%- className %>" type="text" value="<%- value %>" onkeyup="myFunction">
  </div>
  <div class="AknFieldContainer-footer">
    <div class="AknFieldContainer-validationErrors validation-errors">
      <% _.each(errors, function (error) { %>
        <div class="AknFieldContainer-validationError">
          <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
          <%- error %>
        </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the right question here is how can I make the value of an input field dynamic and dependable from the input?

This is first picture: [image]

And the `formData` which is sent then looks like this.

```
{
  "code": "city_action",
  "attributes": ["sku", "template", "sorting"],
  "attribute_as_label": "sku",
  "attribute_requirements": {
    "ecommerce": ["sku", "template"]
  },
  "labels": [],
  "template_code": "testTest"
}:
```

And I have exactly he same `formData` if I add something like shown on a picture below. [image]

Comment: *how can I make the value of an input field dynamic and dependable*  Please explain what you think dynamic and dependable mean? What *exactly* are you trying to do? And, what are the `<% %>` indicating? Are you using server-side code here too?

Comment: So exactly means - I want to add whatever user have added to the input field to the value of that input field and when the user clicks on save button, I want this updated input field. 
<%- fieldname%> - this is the value that we are getting from require.js

Comment: I have added the `require.js` tag to your question. *I want to add whatever user have added to the input field to the value of that input field* That makes no sense. Please clarify what you are trying to do. Be specific.

Comment: Hmmm, well I don't know how to explain it. It doesn't make sense for me too. But let me edit my question in order for you to see.

Comment: Does it now make any sense ?

Comment: @FortuneSoldier There's an extra `:` in the `formData` at the end. Is it correct?

Comment: Hmm, nicely seen. I am going to see about that. Thanks Danny.

Comment: Let me know if anyone needs anything else to see. Any logs or anything ? I am clueless.